# Is there a difference between returning a promise from async or or normal function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

For some time I've been wondering if the `async` keyword when simply returning a promise is not redundant.

Consider the following:

```
async function thePromise() {
    const v = await Inner();
    return v+1;
}

async function wrapper() {
    return thePromise();
}
```

I've been wondering for the `wrapper` function, since it doesn't wait inside the promise for resolution, wouldn't the async keyword be redundant? And shouldn't we use just:

```
function wrapper() {
    return thePromise();
}
```

The obvious drawback is that this format obfuscates that we use promises, but besides that: is there any actual difference between returning a promise from an asynchronous function or a normal function?

Comment: i think you are right @paul23

Answer (score 0):

Consider this simple demo: -

```
var me = {
    name: 'Shivendra'
}
// promise creation
var myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (me) {
        resolve(me.name==='Shivendra')
    }
    else {
        reject(new Error("Oh no !"))
    }
}
)

function wrapper(){
    return myPromise;
}
// promise consumption
wrapper().then(res => {
    if (res) {
        console.log("Promised passed")
        console.log(me)
    }
    else {
        console.log("Promise was failed")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Since There is no such thing as a Promise of a Promise in javascript, those are equivalent

```js
// code 1
promise1.then(() => {
  //...
  return promise2;
}).then(f);

// is equivalent to code 2

promise1.then(() => {
  //...
  return promise2.then(f);
});
```

So same thing happens with async functions, returning a promise from an async function is equivalent to returning the awaited expression

```js
// code 3
async () => {
  // ...
  return p;
}

// is equivalent to code 4
async () => {
  // ...
  return await p;
}
```

One thing to note, is that does not apply to arrays of promises and such. For those scenarios, you can wrap the array with a `Promise.all` to turn the array of promises into a promise of an array or code your own for other data structures.